# jQuery select just the text in a div

Tags: jquery

Is there a succint way of getting just the text in a div, that also has child elements in it, using jQuery?

For example - how would I extract "Some text" from the html below:

```
<div id="mydiv">
   <img src="...
   Some text
</div>
```

Comment: Please go through the `jquery` doc first then you will get to know how we do?

Comment: You can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173194/select-all-div-text-with-single-mouse-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var text = $("#mydiv")
               .clone()    //clone the element
               .children() //select all the children
               .remove()   //remove all the children
               .end()      //go back to selected element
               .text();    //get the text of element
```

Comment: This works and is also very instructive, but certainly not as succinct as I would have liked it

Comment: @Graham I agree, it would be nice if jQuery included some overloads for the text() method that removed the childrens text. But since it doesn't exist at the moment, you need to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example with

`$('#mydiv').text();`

and it worked fine for me!

Comment: This takes all the html of the div.  I'm using version 1.7.1

Comment: This only works because img has no text in it.  Using an element with text in it instead will also return the text in that element.

Answer (score 0):

Using .text() function to any element will extract the text within that tag

```
$("#elementname").text(); will work
```

here is the sampe
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XnN7w/)

Comment: Works for the example given, but if I change the img to <p>whatever</p> it doesn't work

Comment: Yea true, Agreed because there isnt any text inside the <tag></tag>
instead its inside a child.