# How to select the html tags with their contents when using selectNodeContents?

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have this bit of code, which I use to get the cursor's position in an editable div :

```
   function getMeCurPos(element){
       if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
          var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
          var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange(); 
          preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
          preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset); 
          caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;  
          return caretOffset;
       }                        
   }
```

The problem is that, the caretOffset returned only counts the textual contents and not the html tags. For eg :

Consider this string in my editable div :
`Hey <b>jony</b>, whats goin on in the | party`

*Cursor is denoted by `|` character.

Doing getMeCurPos(ele) returns : `30` but it should return `37`. It doesn't count `b` tags

Comment: Anyone with an answer.....

Comment: been trying to set up your code. can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows a functional version of your current code?

Comment: Any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You may create a temp `div` in which you can put your `preCaretRange` and where you can use `textContent` or `innerText` on it. This won't take the HTML length, but the text around it.

```
 function getMeCurPos(element){
       if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
          var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
          var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange(); 
          preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
          preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset); 
          var temp = document.createElement("div");
          temp.innerHTML = preCaretRange.toString();
          var sanitized = temp.textContent || temp.innerText;
          caretOffset = sanitized.length;
          return caretOffset;
       }                        
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbUJe/)

Comment: Still this only returns the text count, and doesn't count the tags.
See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tanya_Arora/KLEbW/)

Comment: @TanyaArora alright, I didn't understand your problem at all. Thought it was the contrary. I'm looking to it

Comment: @TanyaArora using a textarea would solve that problem : http://jsfiddle.net/KLEbW/1/

Answer (score 1):

For getting the selection both as text and as DOM nodes you can use the `cloneContents()` in the Javascript selection-range.
HTML as below

```js
function getMeCurPos(element) {
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    var range = window.getSelection();
    cloned.innerHTML = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < range.rangeCount; i++) {
      cloned.append(range.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
    }

    var sanitized = cloned.innerHTML;
    caretOffset = sanitized.length;
    return caretOffset;
  }
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable="true" id="test" onclick="alert(getMeCurPos(this))">Test1<br>Test2<br>Test3<br>Test4</p>
<br>
Cloned: <span id="cloned"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the code from this article:
[Select all DIV text with single mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173194/select-all-div-text-with-single-mouse-click)

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function selectText(containerid) {
                    if (document.selection) {
                        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
                        range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
                        range.select();
                    } else if (window.getSelection) {
                        var range = document.createRange();
                        range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
                        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
                    }
                }
            </script>

            <div id="selectable" onclick="selectText('selectable')">http://example.com/page.htm</div>
```