# select text within a div throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery

This `$("#grid_modal div")[0].childNodes[0]` captures all the text in a given div. But how come adding `.select()` to the end causes an error?

```
$("#grid_modal div")[0].childNodes[0].select()
//TypeError: Object #<Text> has no method 'select'
```

Text has not method select? How can I get around this?

Comment: Because by adding `[0]` you're getting the DOM node, not the jQuery object, and then you're trying to use jQuery again (`.select()`) on the DOM node. That's like trying to do `document.getElementById('foo').closest('tr')`.

Comment: are you trying to get all the text in a div, or start a selection around all text in a given div bc the latter i think you'll need to make content editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to call the [`select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Input.select?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Input.select) Javascript method.

> For an Input or TextArea element, this will focus the element and select all the text in it.

However you haven't got an `input` or a `textarea` element. You've actually got a text node. You were trying to find the first child element of the div, but there was a text node before it, and text nodes are selected when you do `childNodes`.

The easy way round this is to use jQuery to do the whole selection instead:

```
$("#grid_modal div").eq(0).children().first()[0].select()
```

You can do it with vanilla Javascript instead. For instance, you can use the [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) property, but this isn't available across all browsers (in particular in IE<9).

```
$("#grid_modal div")[0].children[0].select()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is giving me `TypeError: Cannot call method 'select' of undefined`. The structure is `<div id="grid_modal"><div>text to select</div></div>`. Any ideas?

Comment: Elements other than `input` and `textarea` elements don't have a `select` method. What do you want to do? Highlight the text? If so, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173194/select-all-div-text-with-single-mouse-click).

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you do `[0]` on the *jQuery Object*, you've effectly left your *jQuery* environment for a vanilla *Node*. This means you can't use *jQuery's* methods, without re-applying it.

```
var node = $("#grid_modal div")[0].childNodes[0];
$(node).select();
```

> This [...] captures all the text in a given div

You're actually getting the first *Node* which is a child of the first *Node* of your `#grid_modal div`, there is no guarantee that this is a text node. If you want text, it may be better to use [`node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)

Comment: @thomas `document.body.select; // undefined`

Comment: @PaulS. `document.querySelector('input').select !== undefined`

Comment: @lonesomeday OP makes no mention of a _HTMLInputElement_ or _HTMLTextAreaElement_ and the error message talks about a _Text Node_, _#Text_.

Comment: I guess it's just for inputs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Input.select

Comment: @PaulS. Yes. Precisely.