# Programmatically select DOM element (as if with mouse) on Safari Mobile?

Tags: javascript, select

Would like to programmatically select HTML within a DOM element, as if the user had selected with a mouse, precisely to avoid making them select with a mouse.

This bit of elegant code from SO post ([Select all DIV text with single mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173194/select-all-div-text-with-single-mouse-click)) works great on laptop browsers I tested (IE, Chrome, FF, Safari on Windows and Mac):

```
    function selectText(el) {
        if (document.selection) {
            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
                range.moveToElementText(el);
            range.select();
            console.log("select 1");
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(el);
            window.getSelection().addRange(range);
                        console.log("select 2");
        }
        else {
          console.log("select 3");
        }
    };
```

**JSFiddle:**  http://jsfiddle.net/z4yMh/7/

But does not work on Safari mobile (see JSFiddle).  The mobile dev console shows he console shows `select 2` indicating the click event is getting called, mobile dev console shows no error (i.e. the methods `selectNode()` don't seem to be null), just nothing happening.

Can't guess why.  Googling is hard as `select` is also used to refer to a different concept jQuery/DOM selectors.

What I'm hoping for is an effect that's like native selection in Safari mobile, as in the picture here:

[image]

This project does not use jQuery, but if that solves the problem jQuery would be fine.

Comment: I guess is not working on Safari Mobile because of the differences between click and touch.

Comment: Good thought.  The click event is getting called.  Update the fiddle and post to verify that's the case.

Comment: @user645715 I updated the jsfiddle you created to show it in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [CSS Ninja](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/ios-clipboard)

> When setting a range iOS Safari won’t actually show the selection as
>   highlighted but if you were to check the document selection it would
>   return the correct content, desktop browsers will show the range
>   selected in the document.
>
> However if you do the same with a user action like tapping the “set
>   selection range” button in the demo the iOS highlight will show up.
>   Another interesting quirk is if I tap the content and bring the
>   keyboard up but don’t dismiss it then refresh the page the
>   programmatically set selection will show the iOS selection highlight.
>
> Another interesting find is if you perform execCommand, which I’ll
>   touch on later in the article, like bold it will apply the command to
>   the selection made and make the iOS selection UI appear.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good find!  This is really useful to me.

Comment: Wow, how do you find links like that?  Created http://jsfiddle.net/z4yMh/19/ per this and @Tom Pace 's .  The event is getting called, it seems to just be not highlighting the selection.    Can't quite seem to find the object to call `execCommand` on.  The only thing that seems to have that method is `document` but the display is not responding. I'm crashing now but back on this in daylight.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @nietonfir but I also updated the jsfiddle, a few times, to see how it would react.

The important point is to replace "click" with one of: touchstart, touchmove, touchend, touchcancel.

```
element.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {...});
```

See it in action here (minus the Mobile Safari selection UI):

http://jsfiddle.net/z4yMh/16/

Comment: Fascinating.  On my ipad, the `'click'` event was enough to enable to trigger the event, and  so I assume for your device `click` was not working and required the `touchstart`?

Comment: The click event had no effect in mobile safari on my iPhone, iOS 6. I've done a lot of mobile safari work using css transforms with the touches and animation.  The click event has never worked, I find it interesting you had success with it on iPad. What iOS version?

Comment: Possibly.  Does the code select the div on your machine?  If so, that's a definite yes.  I still can't get Safari to programmatically select the DIV once the event is triggered (the primary goal).  But I do greatly appreciate your tremendous help on adding the 'touchstart' (the next problem I would have faced). Strangely, click does work on my ipad ios 6.1.3.  Added a +1.  That's not even close to justice though.

Comment: Yes, on my iPhone (very hard to work with jsfiddle on iPhone!) the div was selected according to window selection ranges.  But the visual part, what is supposed to appear when you long-press on something usually, and get the Select/Select All pop-up, that doesn't appear with stability.  Various places online say Mobile Safari is buggy and inconsistent with that.