# How to select HTML content in range

Tags: javascript, html

I need to select my HTML content ( as in highlight text so I can copy it). I want to create a button that selects all content between two `<div>` or two `<p>`(any tag really). Check out [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvoxYQ) for what I need to select.

I have found some selection ideas, but I am not sure (kinda confused)

```
<input onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, 9999)" value="Sample Text" />
var range = document.createRange();
var sel = window.getSelection();
range.setStart(el.childNodes[2], 5);
range.collapse(true);
```

I want it to create range by a two tags. 
Thanks for any help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Denis from [Select all DIV text with single mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173194/select-all-div-text-with-single-mouse-click) you should use

```
function SelectText(element) {
 if (document.selection) {
  var range = document.body.createTextRange();
  range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(element));
  range.select();
 } else if (window.getSelection) {
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(document.getElementById(element));
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);
 }
}
```

to select the text in the element from the parameter called `element`.

To make sure you can select your table you have to put it in a `<div>`:

```
<div id="foo">
 <table>
  ...
 </table>
</div>
```

You have to do the same thing with any other thing

```
<div id="bar">
 <p>
  ...
 </p>
</div>
```

You can then select that table with this button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="SelectText(foo)" value="Select table">
```

And for the other `div`s:

```
<input type="button" onclick="SelectText(bar)" value="Select p">
```

Let me know if it works
Happy coding :) -Charlie

Comment: Thank you for your post I have added the updated code not sue why it is not working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvoxYQ?editors=101)

Comment: Bob, I tried it in a local file under Firefox 33/Ubuntu 14.04 and that works, the CodePen didn't, however. I don't know what is causing this problem

Comment: @bobsmitha I found a working JavaScript on another topic on this site. I checked and this works in both Firefox and Chrome. Let me know if this works for you ;) Here's a CodePen-Snippet: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbOQpo