# How to make text selectable on my web page?

Tags: html, css

All text and all elements on website acting like image when I trying to do any selection.
website:
http://esther.vladimirmilovanovic.rs

Comment: If you use Chrome Check if you have this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883622/user-select-all-inheritance-not-working-in-chrome-62

Comment: Selection not work in any browser not just Chrome