# how to select text with jquery using focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, focus

I am trying to select the text inside the `span` element by this code but I do not succeed in it:

```
<span class="selectme">this text should be selected by click</span> 

$(".selectme").live('focus', function() { $(this).select(); });
```

This one, below,  is working well:

```
<input value="this text should be selected by click" class="selectme">

$("input.selectme").live('focus', function() { $(this).select(); });
```

How can I make it work with the `span` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`span` doesn't works like `input`, so the short answer is that you can't do that. It doens't even has the `focus` event by default.

But there is a workaround. You need to add `tabindex="-1"` to make it focusable and use `window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(this);` to select it's value:

```js
$(".selectme").on('focus', function() { 
    window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="selectme" tabindex="-1">this text should be selected by click</span>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20079910/1267304)

Also [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is *deprecated*, use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.