# How Can I Select A Variable To Copy?

Tags: javascript

```
var delayBecauseFirebase = 1000;
setTimeout(function() {
      var buttonShowJ = document.getElementById("buttonShow");
      var messagesInJ = document.getElementById("messagesIn");
      if(buttonShowJ)
      {
        buttonShowJ.addEventListener("click",function(){
          var info = messagesInJ.innerHTML.replace(`<button id="buttonShow">Copy</button>`,"");
          info.select(); \\**(!HERE, because that doesnt works)**
          document.execCommand("copy");
        });
      }else{
        console.log("error");
      }
}, delayBecauseFirebase);
```

I want to select the "text" inside ***info*** to can do

> document.execCommand("copy");

But i dont know how can i use ***select*** for that *var*.

Comment: Did you try innerText? https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: @GermanFaller yes, but with innerText "Copy" doesn't disappear. But thx.

Comment: Your problem is that variable info is a string, not an element.  Select is not a method of a string.  Instead, you probably should consider using Clipboard.writeText(info), or put info in an html element that you select.

Comment: so, why not having 3 elements ```<Div parent><div text></div><btn/></div>``` easier to get just the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could work

- In the HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="messagesIn">
    ...Some Text
  </div>
  <button id="buttonShow">Copy</button>
</div>
```

- Then in the code

```js
var delayBecauseFirebase = 1000;

function copyText(){
    //Select your text
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById("messagesIn"));
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);

    //Call copy command
    document.execCommand("copy");
}

function addClickListener() {
    var buttonShowJ = document.getElementById("buttonShow");
    if(buttonShowJ){
        buttonShowJ.addEventListener("click", copyText);
    }else{
        console.error("Copy button not found");
    }
}

setTimeout(addClickListener, delayBecauseFirebase);
```

Recomended post:

- [Select all DIV text with single mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173194)
- [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212)

Comment: Thx for help, btw "document.execCommand("copy")" doesnt work if "info" arent select. (Based on what i read). So that is why i asked this. And with Clipboard.writeText(info) the same error like select() that isnt a function.

Comment: I was looking for that, now, check the edited answer

Comment: I checked and I understand what u said. Ur Code is more Clean and work ^^.

Comment: @MitsworthSCZD so, please if this works and you consider as a correct answer, Accept this answer. :D