# Double click select all text

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I'm using selectizejs to an input field. The problem is when I double click the input, it doesn't select all the text within it. Below is the function that I've come up with but doesn't work:

```
$('.selectize-input').on('dblclick', function() {
  var item = $(this).find('.item')
  console.log(item)
  item.text().select();
});
```

[image]

Comment: Item is like an array, so try like:  **item[0].select()**

Comment: @Radeanu Im getting .select is not a function

Comment: Would this function get you started? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20079910 (implemented as something as `window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(item[0]);`