# How to select entire lines of text when selection partially covers multiple lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

In the example below place the cursor anywhere in the middle of two lines, eg. from 'ipsum' to the following 'lorem'. The following words will be selected: `ipsum dolor sit lorem`

On clicking the button I need to get the full lines in the selection. In the above example I should retrieve the following words:
`lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum`

Does anyone know how I can do this?

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.modify('move', 'backward', 'paragraphboundary');
  sel.modify('extend', 'right', 'paragraphboundary');
});
```

```css
div {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable>lorem ipsum
dolor sit
lorem ipsum

lorem ipsum
dolor sit
lorem ipsum
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: It was answered already,here is the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173194/select-all-div-text-with-single-mouse-click

Comment: @Nikkkshit - seems it is not answered on your link. At least - not in the accepted answer

Comment: Yes it is, the method in the accepted answer works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wrgxyhu2/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - no, it is not. Please read my question carefully - `block between...`

Comment: Did you check the fiddle example? The position of the cursor has absolutely *no bearing* on the result - it will always select all text in the element.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - of course I tried. I don't need `entire text` - I need entire `block of text` between `\n\n` and `\n\n` or between start and next `\n\n` - just as I wrote in post

Comment: In that case your terminology needs to be improved. I will edit your question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I'm sure - my terminology - between start and `\n\n` - or between two `\n\n`  - is more precize. But never mind, thanks